# O que fazer quando a resposta possível é uma má prática?

Tags: debate

Quando uma pergunta possui todos os elementos para uma possível resposta, ou seja, o autor claramente consegue explicar o seu problema, está dentro do escopo permitido pelo SOpt, é inserido todos os elementos de suporte como código, imagens e por vezes links, etc... porém a resposta possível induz a uma má prática, não por culpa do autor, mas sim porque a pergunta assim exige.

Por exemplo, o utilizador faz a seguinte pergunta:

> Tenho um formulário de login com o method="GET". Como verificar no meu login.php se o utilizador e a senha foram preenchidos?

O autor insere na pergunta o HTML com o formulário e o `login.php` com o código utilizado.

Existe uma resposta válida para a pergunta, porém é uma má prática passar senhas via `GET`.

Como proceder?

- Deixar uma resposta e uma explicação sobre a má prática.
- Deixar uma resposta e um comentário sobre a má prática.
- Não responder e deixar um comentário sobre a má prática.

Embora seja um assunto óbvio para quem tem mais experiência, esse tipo de pergunta (e outras do gênero) é bem comum para quem está começando.

Ao responder a questão, certamente seria marcada como válida e então poderia ser utilizada como solução para iniciantes.

Não seria ideal existir algo que sinalizasse a pergunta como sendo má prática?

Penso que isso iria enriquecer a comunidade, mostrar que afinal também é possível aprender errando, sem apresentar o conteúdo de forma equivocada.

Comment: Realmente seria bom, e já "existe" algo assim são votos de fechamento, mas requer 20k e que a resposta tenha -1, é uma funcionalidade dificil da maioria dos usuários conseguirem :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não acho que deveria ser removida ou fechada, até porque pode causar uma certa confusão uma vez que a pergunta respeita os princípios do SOpt. Deixa-la e sinaliza-la como má prática poderia até ser uma ajuda para quem está com a mesma dúvida, iria enriquecer o site e não iria gerar conteúdos "impróprios".

Comment: Entendi a sugestão, acho que é pra isso que existe os downvotes, senão será duas ferramentas pra mesma tarefa, concorda?

Comment: Em algum lugar da resposta é bom constar que é má-prática, e por quê. Se a resposta não inclui isso, certamente é incompleta. Vale a pena no mínimo avisar o autor sobre isso. Negativar ou não fica a critério de cada um.

Comment: Já quanto ao tipo de pergunta, se for clara, no escopo, etc., não vejo motivos para fechar nem negativar.

Comment: Downvote. A resposta não deve, necessariamente, ser composta por boas práticas. Ela deve *resolver o problema*.

Answer (score 16):

A solução é simples:

## Postar uma resposta com boas práticas

Aqui vai como eu responderia a pergunta:

> Amigo, eu sei que isso não é exatamente o que você espera, mas primeiramente, **não use GET** para fazer o login.
>
> O motivo é que fazer isso é inseguro. Por exemplo, vamos supor que este seja o seu formulário:
>
> ```
> <form action="login" method="GET">
>     <input type="text" name="login" />
>     <input type="password" name="senha" />
>     <input type="submit" value="Efetuar o login" />
> </form>
> ```
>
> E vamos supor que você preencha isso com o login "fulano" e a senha "$3nh4". Eis a URL para a qual o navegador enviará o comando:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/login?login=fulano&senha=$3nh4
> ```
>
> Observe que a senha aparece na URL de forma bem visível. Essa URL vai ser enviada para vários lugares diferentes a fim de se localizar o site, e em todos eles, o login e a senha serão exibidos de forma nua e crua podendo então serem utilizados de forma indevida. *(...blablablabla, mais explicações sobre os problemas que isso tem ...)*
>
> A solução é você utilizar o método POST:
>
> ```
> <form action="login" method="POST">
>     <input type="text" name="login" />
>     <input type="password" name="senha" />
>     <input type="submit" value="Efetuar o login" />
> </form>
> ```
>
> E então no lado do PHP, você obtém os campos do formulário da seguinte forma:
>
> ```
> $login = $_POST["login"];
> $senha = $_POST["senha"];
> ```
>
> Ainda há mais uma questão importante, que é que você deve usar HTTPS ao invés de HTTP, para ter certeza que o conteúdo está devidamente critografado. Caso contrário, o conteúdo dos pacotes HTTP trafegados ainda mostraão a senha nua e crua em seu corpo. *(...blablablabla, mais explicação sobre HTTP vs HTTPS e como usar isso no formulário...)*
>
> Uma outra opção é usar a **Basic Authentication** *(...blablablabla, explicação sobre o que é isso...)*

Enfim, este tipo de resposta:

- Explica ao que o autor da pergunta o que está errado na sua pergunta e porque o que ele quer não pode ou não deve ser feito.
- Explica para ele como fazer corretamente a fim de atingir o objetivo almejado.
- Explica quais outras opções ele poderia considerar, bem como suas nuances, vantagens e desvantagens.

É verdade que isso não respode diretamente a pergunta "*Como verificar no meu login.php se o utilizador e a senha foram preenchidos?*", mas ao meu ver, deve-se ter o senso crítico de perceber-se que a pergunta é uma pequena parte de alguma coisa maior, aonde o objetivo do autor da pergunta provavelmente não é simplesmente "*ler os parâmetros de login via GET*", e sim "*efetuar o login de um usuário em seu sistema*".

Comment: Perfeito. Ajuda o autor a resolver o problema (pegar a informações do formulário, no caso) e explica como e porque evitar a má prática.